# Tuning the birthday paradox

Tags: probability, sampling

There are *m* disjoint sets *X*<sub>*i*</sub> and a function *f* : [1..*n*] → [1..*m*] such that *Y*<sub>*j*</sub> = *X*<sub>*f*(*j*)</sub>.  I am given oracles / samples from random variables *x*<sub>*i*</sub> and *y*<sub>*j*</sub> which uniformly select elements from *X*<sub>*i*</sub> and *Y*<sub>*j*</sub> respectively, but each sample from *x*<sub>*i*</sub> and *y*<sub>*j*</sub> has a cost (independent of *i* or *j*).  I would like to compute *f* by sampling from *x* and *y* and looking for collisions, since *X*<sub>*i*</sub> and *Y*<sub>*j*</sub> are either equal or disjoint, but I'd like to keep the cost down, so using the fewest samples from *x* and *y*.

If *n* and *m* were approximately equal, I think I should just sample evenly from *x* and *y*, and the birthday paradox should allow me to identify at least one value of *f*(*j*) fairly quickly (taking about the square root of the size of the largest set in *Y*), and I think in general all of *f* fairly quickly.

However, in my situation *m* is large compared to *n* (say *m* = 50000 different *X*s, *n* = 50 different *Y*s).  Each *X*<sub>*i*</sub> has about 10<sup>6</sup> elements.  It seems in this case one should "focus" on *y* more than *x* since most *X*<sub>*i*</sub> will end up being irrelevant (but still expensive), but on the other hand, only sampling from *x* once per *i* seems to completely negate the birthday paradox, requiring an expected number of |*Y*<sub>*j*</sub>| samples from *y*<sub>*j*</sub> to find *f*(*j*).

> How often should I sample from *y* compared to *x* in order to minimize the total (expected) number of samples required to compute *f*?

In other words, express *p* as a function of *m*, *n*, *k* = max(|*X*<sub>*i*</sub>|) where 0 ≤ *p* ≤ 1 is the minimizing argument of the function which gives the expected number of samples of the process which samples uniformly from the *x*<sub>*i*</sub> with probability *p*, and uniformly from the *y*<sub>*j*</sub> with probability 1−*p*, and stops as soon as *f* has been computed (that is, as soon as for every *j*, one has sampled a value of *y*<sub>*j*</sub> equal to a value sampled from an *x*<sub>*i*</sub>).

Comment: Similar version at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83200/tuning-the-birthday-paradox

Comment: When a problem is stated abstractly in mathematical terms, the definitions and descriptions have to be *very clear* and *accurate,* otherwise the whole thing falls apart.  The question as stated on math.SE is fairly coherent, but the version here does not provide enough information to make sense of the question.  Please post just *one* question on *one* site and make it stand alone so that it can be accurately understood.

Comment: @whuber: what part do you find confusing?

Comment: Lots.  I find it extremely difficult to understand exactly what is going on here or what process you are trying to model.  Given the absence of any replies on either the math site or here, I suspect that many others may be having similar difficulties.  I have the overwhelming impression that by telling us your *real* problem, rather than your mathematical abstraction of it, you could describe it in a couple of sentences much more clearly than you have done in three paragraphs and that this would interest people in providing answers.

Comment: The principal reason for closing, by the way, is that this is really a cross-posting.  The problem is better articulated in the version on the math site, so it seemed best to close the one here.  If you would like to act on the suggestion over at math to post the question here, then please flag that one for migration and it will get moved by a moderator.  I won't close the question if it gets migrated here, but I would encourage you to consider reformulating it in a way that is more readily understandable.

Comment: This is the real problem. I am a mathematician. Each set Xi is a collection of descriptions of a mathematical object, and xi produces a random description, but this takes time. f is the unknown identification between a sequence of these objects and the canonical list in X.  I have tried p = 0.5 and p → 0, and neither seems optimal.  I suspect there is a simple function along the lines of p = n/(m+n), but this is not quite right.

Comment: It actually helps to know the real problem, even though it's mathematical, because that automatically rules out all kinds of behaviors that would worry us in other contexts (essentially, questions concerning how accurately known your distributional assumptions are) and it provides a model for thinking about the process.  My own sense is that this is an interesting problem and that a straightforward presentation of it on this site might elicit a number of useful suggestions.  Because questions on the math site usually get answers within minutes, and yours hasn't, consider migrating it here.